# Fallback input for ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, cpu

I'm doing some transcoding from a third-party remote input stream that I do not control.

This input stream has errors from time to time, that I would like to mitigate before sending the stream to my transcoding pipeline, avoiding this way some possible problems in the output.

I have several ideas regarding different problems. But the most basic scenario I would like to set up is as follows: **when the stream is down, or it somehow loses some frames, I want to fill that video gap with a secondary input (like a blank screen, for example)**.

For this simple task, I would like to use `ffmpeg`. I know it can mix, let's say, an input stream with a fullscreen black square static image. However, I have to deal with this other condition: ffmpeg would run in the same infraestructure for the actual transcoding pipeline. That infraestructure must use its computing power for rendering the output. So, whatever `ffmpeg` command I end up using should use the minimum possible computing power.

My actual problem: if I use `-vcodec copy`, in order to use minimum CPU, I can't alter the original stream. But if I alter the original stream (by mixing it with some other stream), the operation uses CPU.

My question: **Is there a way to use `-vcodec copy`, but with a fallback input (instead of a mixed one) for when there are video gaps in the primary stream?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question: [How to display static image if the input stream ends using ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/how-to-display-static-image-if-the-input-stream-ends-using-ffmpeg)